# Why do otherwise smart people commit obvious fallacies?

Tags: fallacies

Is it a mistake on their part, or is it part of a rhetorical strategy to convince more people, hoping that they don't realize a fallacy has been committed?

In particular many theists and atheists who engage in discussion are using these fallacies. For example, Richard Dawkins and Sam Harris, otherwise smart men, often resort to using strawman arguments, appeal to ridicule, ad hominem, etc etc.

Why?

EXAMPLE:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrDlVLbtKbQ

Comment: Because people aren't robots (or vulcans for that matter) who are always perfectly logical. This sounds more like a psychology question ("why do people do certain things?") than a philosophy question.

Comment: I think it is an adequate question since many professional philosophers are guilty of it.

Comment: Fallacies are popular with people who don't have an argument but do have a strong opinion. In the cases you mention the problem seems to be very visible and terminal but as nir notes, it's a widely popular technique .  .

Comment: @Not_Here at least I'm trying to be a Vulcan....

Comment: I don't think that this is a philosophy question per se, but one of cognitive science and psychology. Tali Sharot talks about it in "The Influential Mind": On certain issues in which people have a deep emotional investment, facts and logic don't change people's minds, because people are deeply committed to them. If anything the opposite happens: the smarter the person - the more able they are to find creative ways to rationalize their point of view, no matter how much it is contradicted by the facts. So people like Dawkins and Harris are actually better at using fallacies than laymen are.

Comment: Because pure logic free from fallacies is distinctly over-rated.  Almost nothing that matters can be formally proven, and everything that cannot be formally proven involves some sort of fallacy.

Comment: Over the years, I've developed instinctive suspicion towards these celebrity intellectuals. Suppose you know you will be shot in the head by stray bullets at any moment, which author do you want to read before you die? None of these fellas.

Answer (score 2):

As with mathematical thinking, logical thinking is not natural for everyone, and even for those who have a natural aptitude for it, it can take time and effort to develop.  It isn't necessarily a function of general intelligence (assuming that actually exists).  This is true not just for the disputants in an argument, but the audience.

If rhetoric is the art of persuasion, therefore, then logic may be only one tool in the rhetorical toolbox, and not necessarily the most immediately effective one either.  Particularly given that logic is often taught only as an elective, it's entirely possible that someone could be smart, well-educated, and persuasive; and yet logically weak.  If so, it's possible this person might not a) care if he or she is logically weak or b) even realize his or her weakness.  Yet more cynically still, one might be logically strong, yet still choose to advance logically weak arguments for effect (like a genuinely powerful wrestler playacting for the cameras on a entertainment-oriented wrestling show).

Of course, for actual validity of argument and certification of conclusion, logic is essential.  But unfortunately that may matter less than one might hope in the marketplace of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Calling someone an idiot is not a logical fallacy, it is an argument in itself. If we agree on premises it can even be a valid argument; however, it is a straw-man fallacy to reject a person's arguments because they are an idiot. I do not think your example is a straw-man argument, Harris just adds the idiot claim to the hypothetical person for rhetorical purposes.

Why are ad hominem fallacies so attractive? Few people are actually swayed by rational reasoning. It's one of many cognitive biases, such as the Fundamental Attribution Error. Thinking takes energy, so humans have built-in shortcuts to make thinking easier and faster. Just imagine if you were to take the time to analyze every argument from every person throughout the day.

The answer is that you should assume that most people, regardless of intelligence or training, are often going to make unsound arguments. It is an ad hominem fallacy to presuppose that a person made a logical error intentionally when it is so easy and common to make such an error accidentally. Discerning intentionality is very difficult, and most likely an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a rant than an answer, but I'm starting to think it's impossible to debate anything meaningful without making a logical fallacy or resorting to axiomatic thinking. Reasoning:

- There are plenty of examples of logical fallacies, but very few (no?) examples of valid logical arguments for controversial issues. In other words, if you're going to debate a controversial issue, you won't get very far with a purely logical argument.
- *Even if* we could get everyone to understand the rules of logic (and many people don't) and agree on what constitutes a logical fallacy, we would then have to debate fundamental principles or axioms.

So, when people ask "why can't everyone discuss controversial issue X logically", the answer is: because it's literally impossible to determine or even agree on fundamental axiomatic truth. We know we exist ("I think; therefore I am"), but everything outside that is speculation.

So, not only are arguments with logical fallacies more convincing (to most people), they're also the *only* arguments you can actually make.